# Transaction rollback not working for CompositeItemWriter

Tags: spring-batch, spring-transactions

Somehow transaction rollback not working for CompositeItemWriter.

I have 2 update queries inside CompositeItemWriter and commit-interval of 20.
Let's say after 15 records, if I get any issue with next update, then Ideally all earlier records should roll back to their earlier state. But I can see those records updated in DB.

Anyone has any idea about the same? I am using 3.0.5.RELEASE version of Spring batch.

Configuration is

```xml
<step id="step1" next="step2">
    <tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager" >
        <chunk reader="reader" writer="customItemWriter" commit-interval="20"/>
        <transaction-attributes propagation="REQUIRES_NEW" isolation="DEFAULT"/>
    </tasklet>
</step>`

<bean id="customItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemWriter">
        <property name="delegates">
            <list>
                <ref bean="updateTable1"/>
                <ref bean="updateTable2"/>
                <ref bean="fileWriter"/>               
            </list>
        </property>
</bean>

<bean id="updateTable1" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter">
        <property name="assertUpdates" value="true"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="itemPreparedStatementSetter">
            <bean class="com.batch.jdbc.Table1PreparedStatementSetter" />           
        </property>
        <property name="sql" 
         value="UPDATE TABLE1 SET STATUS = ? WHERE COLUMN1_ID = ?"/>
</bean>

<bean id="updateTable2" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter">
        <property name="assertUpdates" value="true"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="itemPreparedStatementSetter">
            <bean class="com.batch.jdbc.Table2PreparedStatementSetter" />           
        </property>
        <property name="sql" 
         value="UPDATE TABLE2 SET STATUS = ? WHERE COLUMN2_ID = ?"/>
</bean>
<bean id="fileWriter" class="x.y.z.CustomFileWriter" />
```

Comment: Have you checked that your datasources are NOT in autocommit mode?

Comment: I have other batches too where I am using JdbcBatchItemWriter (single writer in step) and there in case of an error/exception, respective updates are getting rolled back.

Comment: If I will mark autocommit false, then in all other batches I have to commit manually and that may not be good. Isn't it ?

Comment: Spring/SpringBatch is responsible to handle the commits. If you set autocommit=true every single statement sent to the DB is committed individually and, therefore, not participating in the transaction managed by Spring. You _absolutely_ have to set autocommit=false or the whole Spring/SpringBatch transactionhandling is completely circumvented.

Comment: I use JNDI and I have set defaultAutoCommit=false as you suggested for dataSource in my app server. But still I am having the same issue. Transaction is not getting rollback.

Comment: Let me add few more details. I have one more custom writer inside CompositeItemWriter which implements ItemWriter(code is updated).

I tried moving 2 DB calls to processor and kept only one writer and tried failure case in writer. In that case also, rollback doesn't work.

Comment: As far as I see, you have a problem with your transactionmanger and/or datasource configuration. It has nothing to do with the springbatch framework. I would suggest, that you setup a simple spring batch project, where you configure the datasoures and the transactionmanager directly, no JNDI, pure spring. Just to have a correclty working example. After that, you have debug and find out, where your JNDI version acts differently. For me, it still looks as if your datasources are in autocommit mode...

Comment: Thanks Hansjoerg. I configure DataSourceTransactionManager instead of JTA and make autocommit false. Rollback works for me.
With JTA, there are few more settings to be done from configuration side. After doing that, Rollback worked for it too. :)